# Stackstabilizer - A Windows 8 Metro Stackoverflow app (version 4, 11-09-2012)

Tags: app, c#, windows

### About Stackstabilizer

Stackstabilizer is a Stackoverflow reader for Windows 8. It helps you browse content on Stackoverflow, and allows you to sign in.

#### In-app search

It provides in-app search (Windows key + Q), and serves as a quick way of getting answers or questions for specific queries.

#### Live tiles

It also includes live tiles right on the start screen that show you featured questions, as well as settings for the application.

#### Unique and useful layout in Metro manner

The colors of the tiles are always based on the tag that the question was asked in. So for instance, C# questions are always red. This never changes if you reinstall later. The colors stay the same.

#### Always ajoure

The program is constantly updated and maintained to ensure that it is the best one out there.

### Timeline

#### Changelog

Version 5 (in development)

- Fixed a minor graphical issue with borders on tiles.
- Added a feedback button that links to this website.

Version 4 (11-09-2012) **(Available to everyone in the store as of 14-08-2012)**

- Improved data fetch time when the application loads on the main page dramatically.
- Fixed a minor bug with the Stackoverflow browser that didn't display highlighting animations correctly.
- Added toast notifications for inbox items as well (for some reason, these only showed for achievements and other notifications before).
- A new tooltip will display in doodle-style showing the user (only once) how to use the app-bar, and that there is one, if he's not familiar with Windows 8.
- Fixed a crash that would occur if packets dropped or the Internet connection was unstable during a data refresh.
- Centered the logo horizontally when in snapped view. It had a weird margin before.
- Fixed a critical bug that caused the headers not to be clickable while in snapped view.
- Improved the tile color generation algorithm for better readability (although not always as pretty - I'll be working on that in the near future).
- Changed the design of large question tiles on the main page. They now look way prettier (and follows Metro design principles) to show more relevant content such as views, score and answer count. A sneek-peak of this can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUal1.png).
- Fixed a bug causing all avatars to be downloaded with a 512x512 resolution instead of the 64x64 resolution. This also causes the app to load faster and use less bandwidth.
- The question tile sections in the main page now only display the top scored questions.
- Fixed an in-app purchase bug.
- Fixed a bug causing the featured and recent section not to have the same amount of elements on some resolutions.
- Fixed an automatic synchronization issue.

Version 3 (11-07-2012)

*Due to some early feedback on version 2 that heavily suggested a few things, I pushed this update out adding a lot of new features, faster than usual.*

- Added in-app question and notification browsing. It no longer boots up in Internet Explorer while in full-screen view.
- Added performance improvements.
- More transitions to ease the eye.
- Added inbox items. Before, only notifications were shown (achievements etc).
- Reorganized the main page of the application so that notifications and inbox items take up less space.

Version 2 (11-05-2012)

- Improved visuals (tiles now have more beautiful colors).
- Added sign-in (you can now sign in to view your notifications).
- Improved settings and background tasks.
- Improved searching speed and accuracy.
- Improved screenshots on this page.

Version 1 (10-05-2012)

- Initial release.

#### Roadmap

- Support for more live tiles. As of now, there can only be a single tile showing all kinds of things, instead of a tile per your open questions for instance.
- Semantic Zoom support for the main page.
- Support for more sections. Right now, it only supports Stackoverflow.
- A tile section on the main page called "Live tile history" where you can see the questions that the live tile has in queue currently (useful if you spot a question in the live tile, but can't get to it easily).
- Support for removing tile sections of choice on the main page.
- <strike>Support for adding comments in the app viewing questions in-app (right now, it just opens a browser window to see questions).</strike> This is now implemented.
- <strike>Support for signing in. Right now, you only get a read-only view of Stackoverflow. You don't have the ability to sign in.</strike> This is now implemented.

### Company link

[Flamefusion](http://flamefusion.net)

### Download link

[Store link](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-US/app/stackstabilizer/b83fe706-ee93-446d-9558-df19f3bbdd0f)

### Screenshots

The screenshots below may be from an older version, although updated regularly. **Most of the current screenshots are from version 2**.

#### The main page (full, signed in)

[image]

#### The main page (snapped, signed in)

[image]

#### The settings page shown with the Settings Charm

As of version 2, settings now synchronize between devices. If you have the same app on 2 devices and you change settings (even when inside the app), the setting will change on the other app instance as well.
[image]

#### The search page shown with the Search Charm (Windows + Q)

[image]

#### The Recent page (full, not signed in)

[image]

#### The Recent page (snapped, not signed in)

[image]

#### The Featured page (snapped, not signed in)

[image]

Comment: I just added new changes and a new release. It's being certified as we speak.

Comment: Yet another release. Added some more detail to the changelog.

Comment: Release 4 now in the store. Major new features. Enjoy!